# Using github api command line gh command, how to find the branch then pull request for a commit sha?

Tags: github, github-api

For a repo `https://github.com/org/project`

My commit sha `fa92b5dcd9748abceab00e290c2ba5c7713d854f`

How to find the branch that this commit is in, by using the `gh` command line?

How to find the pull request that this commit is in, by using the `gh` command line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json"  /repos/OWNER/REPO/commits/COMMIT_SHA/pulls`

It will give you list of PRs the commit was a part of. You will have to filter the json using tools like `jq` to get the suitable portion from the output.

I tried this command for my repo and it worked.

For more information, check this doc page. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits#list-pull-requests-associated-with-a-commit